# Iterate through a set of icons and importing them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wanted to know if I could `import` a number of sequential files in this case SVGs using a loop of some kind so as not to manually type each file up.

The code below is what I am trying but apparently:
`Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`.

I tried a `for` loop mixed with some template literals :shrug:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
   import icon${i} from './menu/icon${i}.svg';
}
```

Please feel free to let me know if I am just off my meds for just thinking in this way and/or noob question --downvote--

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you tagged this as reactjs.  I think what would make your life easier is doing it the reactjs way.  You can have a module that exports an array of svg components.

For example you could have a menu icons directory that contains an index.js file and your .svg files.

```
icons
├── icon1.js
├── icon2.js
├── icon3.js
└── index.js
```

where index.js would look something like this:

```
export * from .;
```

And then you would make your .svg files into a component like such:

```
export default () => <svg>/* add your svg data here */</svg>;
```

that way you could import the icons directory inside the component that you would like to use them in like this:

```
import * as icons from icons;
```

and use your svg component like this:

```
<div>
    <icons.icon1 />
    <icons.icon2 />
    <icons.icon3 />
</div>
```

Comment: so first of all thank you for your attention to detail, I did everything but I can't get the icons to show and get this error `50:15-26 "export 'icon1' (imported as 'icons') was not found in './icons'` do i need to name each `default export` in each icon file?

Comment: @darham, yes, each icon file will contain a default export.  Also, i made a mistake.  I will edit the answer.  ```<icons.menu1 />``` should match the name of the file, like so: ```<icons.icon1 />```

Comment: still getting an error like this:`"export 'icon1' (imported as 'icons') was not found in './assets/icons'`, side note I really want this method to work :P

Comment: so apparently you can't mix default and named exports. but you got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `require(your_path)`.
In this case,

```
const icons = {}
for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
   icons[i] = require('./menu/icon${i}.svg';)
}
```